# I do not understand the behavior of this return statement

Tags: java

Please have a look at this

```
public String getDateAndTime(long rowid){
    CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.
              rawQuery("select created from testRecords where rowid = ?", new String[] { Long.toString(rowid) }); 
    if (cursor != null)
        {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String datandtime= null;
        datandtime=cursor.getString(0);
        db.close();
        return datandtime;
        }
    db.close();    
    return null;

}
```

Now I am obviopusly missing someting important:

**if the cursor is not null I would e expect the whole metod to return `datandtime`**

BUT IT DOES NOT HAPPEN SO:

if the cursor is not null the execution continues and goes to the end `return null`

returning a null.

Please what am I missing here?

---

Please, why close???

Comment: Are you sure that the cursor is actually not null? Furthermore, you do `dateandtime = cursor.getString(0);`. Are you certain that `dateandtime` is also not null?

Comment: Get the String dateandtime declaration outside if statement. In the if statement asign value to dateandtime=cursor.getString(0). Put the return statement return dataandtime outside if method (replace return null with return dataandtime).

Comment: datandtime could also be null from the line datandtime=cursor.getString(0). Check it first. Also are you sure cursor is not null? add some debug code there like system.out.println(cursor)

Comment: And please use Java Notation Convention for variables, e.g. for dataandtime must be dataAndTime. It is more readable.

Comment: May be `datandtime` is null ..

Comment: @MihaiC yes I debugged, it's not null

Answer (score 1):

Change `cursor.getString(0)` to `cursor.getString(1)`.  Database columns are always counted from `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

if cursor is not null it return `datandtime` and stop here. So it doesn't execute this line: `return null;`

Comment: @LisaAnne than is `datandtime` null?!

Comment: @LisaAnne Have you tried to use a debugger to see whats happend?

Answer (score 0):

It's made a query to a database and the result placed into cursor.
If the result is different from null then cursor takes the value of the first String from the query and returns it.
On the other hand, if the result of cursor is null, then the return statement is null.

Have a nice code!

Comment: Try to debug it and see if what @MihaiC is happening. Could be that the first string from the cursor is null

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

cursor.getString(0) is null

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
public String getDateAndTime(long rowid){
    CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    String datandtime= null;
    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.
              rawQuery("select created from testRecords where rowid = ?", new String[] { Long.toString(rowid) }); 
    if (cursor != null)
        {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        datandtime=cursor.getString(0);
        }
    db.close();    
    return datandtime;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this works, but I do not understand why my code does not work

Comment: I guess it's because you are forcing to return null at the end of method. If you want to see the flow, try to debug as many others mentioned, it's the best way to understand where it goes wrong.